# Numpy.where uses

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Use numpy.where to get all (R, G,B) in a numpy.array with a definite value of R, G and B

The problem is i'm not sure i can use numpy.where to get what i want :

i tried the following code :

```
L = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
print(numpy.where(L==(1,1,1)))
```

> > (array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))

and i understand it's returning me the coordinates of every element == 1
but i would like it to return the index in L of the element equal to (1,1,1) :

> > array([1,2])

Comment: `numpy.where((L==(1,1,1)).all(-1))` because you want all three channels to match.

Comment: thanks that's exactly what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`numpy.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero) together with `np.all` (to ensure that each of RGB matches):

```
>>> numpy.nonzero(numpy.all(L == (1, 1, 1), axis=1))[0]
array([1, 2])
```

Comment: What do you gain by replacing the perfectly good `where` with `argwhere` here?

Comment: @PaulPanzer You're right `np.all` is the important part. Thanks.