# How do I use numpy.where to find indices with a complex condition?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
# A JPG for example with RGB
x = np.zeros(shape=[5,5,3]) 
x[1,1] = np.array([1,2,3])

def rgb_equals(a, b, tolerance=0):
    return np.max(np.absolute(np.subtract(a, b))) <= tolerance
```

I've seen this StackOverflow example:
[Numpy.where uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526150/numpy-where-uses)

```
numpy.nonzero(numpy.all(x == (1, 1, 1), axis=1))[0]
```

But that is doing a simple '=='.
How about the more complex rgb_equals?

I understand I need to create a boolean array to pass into numpy.where, however the StackOverflow example only has simple less than/greater than examples: [Creating a boolean array by testing if each element in numpy array is between 2 numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356461/creating-a-boolean-array-by-testing-if-each-element-in-numpy-array-is-between-2)

Thanks!

Comment: What is `a` and `b`, how do you call `rgb_equals`?

Comment: `a` and `b` would be a 1d array of length 3.
`a` could be from `x`, and `b` would be user defined.
So I could pass in `x[1,1], (1,2,4), tolerance=1` and expect to return `True`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64435299/understanding-numpy-where talks more about `where/nonzero`.  The key in your case is constructing a boolean condition array that is True for the elements you want, and False for the others.  `where` just finds the `True`.

Comment: How could I construct the boolean array given my array `x` and condition function `rgb_equals`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [82]: x = np.zeros(shape=[5,5,3])
    ...: x[1,1] = np.array([1,2,3])
    ...: 
In [83]: x
Out[83]: 
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 2., 3.],                 # the nonzero pixel
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Looking for the nonzero pixel:

```
In [84]: x==[1,2,3]
Out[84]: 
array([[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True],               # the pixel
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]]])
In [85]: (x==[1,2,3]).all(axis=2)
Out[85]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],      # the pixel
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

Using `nonzero` on that:

```
In [86]: np.nonzero((x==[1,2,3]).all(axis=2))
Out[86]: (array([1]), array([1]))
In [87]: x[np.nonzero((x==[1,2,3]).all(axis=2))]
Out[87]: array([[1., 2., 3.]])
```

Other ways to look for that pixel:

Exact match:

```
In [95]: np.linalg.norm(x-[1,2,3],axis=2)
Out[95]: 
array([[3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739],
       [3.74165739, 0.        , 3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739],
       [3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739],
       [3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739],
       [3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739, 3.74165739]])
```

but not a good match with [1,1,1]:

```
In [96]: np.linalg.norm(x-[1,1,1],axis=2)
Out[96]: 
array([[1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081],
       [1.73205081, 2.23606798, 1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081],
       [1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081],
       [1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081],
       [1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081, 1.73205081]])
```

or

```
In [98]: np.max(np.abs(x-[1,2,3]), axis=2)
Out[98]: 
array([[3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 0., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]])
```

Comment: Thanks!
The last example is exactly what I needed.
With the new out array I can easily do np.where(out_array <= threshold).